Delta table column mapping support in Athena/Glue
I'm confused by AWS documentation regarding compatibility with delta tables.
We need to delete a column that is the "column mapping" feature supported in delta-lake 1.2.0 and we do it through spark sql and we're forced to specify parameters for our table in S3:
'delta.columnMapping.mode' = 'name',
'delta.minReaderVersion' = '2',
'delta.minWriterVersion' = '5'

https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-column-mapping.html
Now we want to update our table in Glue but the crawler fails because it uses Glue version 3 for crawling and isn't compatible with delta lake 1.2.0.
https://repost.aws/questions/QUyDYz31OnREGxy7gz2qIeuw/error-internal-service-exception-of-glue-crawler
We tried to create the table through Athena that states:

Column mapping and timestampNtz – Delta column mapping, which allows
Delta table columns and the underlying Parquet file columns to use
different names, and timestamp without timezone (timestampNtz) are
supported.
Delta Lake reader version – Delta Lake reader protocol up to version 3
is supported.

(nothing about the writer though)
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/delta-lake-tables.html
But it fails with:

Delta protocol version is too new for Athena DDL engine

So how is column mapping supported if you can't really add the table to Glue and query it?
